# Can't install sense plugin for Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, sense

I am trying to install sense plugin for elasticsearch/kibana.
I have successfully installed Kibana but when following the instruction on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/installing.html
I type :
`./kibana plugin --install elastic/sense`, on the bin directory inside kibana folder, and I get :

```
 ERROR  unknown command plugin

  Usage: bin/kibana [command=serve] [options]

  Kibana is an open source (Apache Licensed), browser based analytics and search dashboard for Elasticsearch.

  Commands:
    serve  [options]  Run the kibana server
    help  <command>   Get the help for a specific command

  "serve" Options:

    -h, --help                 output usage information
    -e, --elasticsearch <uri>  Elasticsearch instance
    -c, --config <path>        Path to the config file, can be changed with the CONFIG_PATH environment variable as well. Use mulitple --config args to include multiple config files.
    -p, --port <port>          The port to bind to
    -q, --quiet                Prevent all logging except errors
    -Q, --silent               Prevent all logging
    --verbose                  Turns on verbose logging
    -H, --host <host>          The host to bind to
    -l, --log-file <path>      The file to log to
    --plugin-dir <path>        A path to scan for plugins, this can be specified multiple times to specify multiple directories
    --plugin-path <path>       A path to a plugin which should be included by the server, this can be specified multiple times to specify multiple paths
    --plugins <path>           an alias for --plugin-dir
```

I can't figure out why I get this error, how can I install sense plugin then ?

Comment: You are missing a `-`, it is `./kibana-plugin` see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/_installing_plugins.html

Comment: Use ./bin/kibana-plugin install elastic/sense instead

Comment: I got the error: Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "No valid url specified." Could you give me a vlid url?

Comment: Try this: `bin/kibana-plugin -i sense -u C:\Path\sense-2.0.0-beta7.tar.gz` -
`$ bin/kibana plugin -i sense -u file:///PATH_TO_SENSE_TAR_FILE`

Comment: Sense is inbuilt, no need to separately install. Launch this http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console as mentioned by @Montenegrodr is correct.

Answer (score 59):

As [wuxiwei](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41072778/5759881) said, Sense was renamed to Console and it is already available on Kibana 5.*. In Kibana, just click on *Dev Tools*:

[image]

Comment: To fully answer the question for those following along with the official guide like the OP was (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current); click the Settings icon right of "VIEW IN SENSE" and paste the following URL : http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console

That way the button will work as expected and you can follow along with all the examples :)

Answer (score 22):

Sense was renamed to Console and is built into Kibana 5. You can find it by clicking on the Dev Tools application.

Comment: Could you give us the online link describing the change? After clicking on the Dev tools, there is nothing by default.

Comment: I don't know why elasticsearch doesn't mention it on install page of Sense.

Answer (score 5):

Sense is now included as Console in Kibana 5.0. You can view the following link: 
`https://github.com/elastic/sense/blob/master/README.md`

There is no need of installing sense seprately, as it is now included as Console. 
elasticsearch and kibana should be running then Console can be found on : 
`http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console`

Answer (score 0):

Manual Downloaded it
Kibana’s bin/plugin script requires direct internet access for downloading and installing Sense. If your server doesn’t have internet access, you can download the Sense tar file from the following link: https://download.elasticsearch.org/elastic/sense/sense-latest.tar.gz

Once downloaded you can install Sense using the following command:

```
$ bin/kibana plugin -i sense -u file:///PATH_TO_SENSE_TAR_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using kibana 6.5.4 and now we use **Dev Tools** instead of using sense plugin. you can input: **http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana** after starting your new version of kibana services and you will find **Dev Tools** on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

It was renamed to `Console`. After you start `Kibana`, you can easily browse `Console` directly from http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console