# How to query Elasticsearch when it is used as an output plugin in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using the following logstash configuration file to feed the kafka topic data and sending it to elasticsearch

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
        topics => ["LDAP"]
    }
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        index => "LDAP"
        }
}
```

Assuming all the data from the topic is sent to elasticsearch, what is the way to query elasticsearch with the index?

Comment: What do you want to query exactly?

Comment: The data that is pushed from LDAP topic to elasticsearch...  i am pushing the following data LDAPReceived='x' kind of data where x is 1 to N.

Answer (score 0):

```
GET LDAP/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

--> curl command

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/LDAP/_search -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}'
```

This query will return all the documents from the LDAP index

Let me know if you don't get any hits with this query

Comment: Can you give me the curl command? For me GET is not working .. Not sure how to make it work.

Comment: HI Prat,do you have sense plugin installed  ?

Comment: No Prasad i dont have sense plugin.. i will install.

Comment: i have updated the answer ,did you check with the curl command ,is it working?

Comment: No. it didnt work. But tried installing Sense from this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/installing.html its failing here too

Comment: Got to know that sense is deprecated and its aavailable in Kibana 5.0 as Console under Dev tools . Captured in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635566/cant-install-sense-plugin-for-kibana?rq=1